# How unsafe is revealing a part of AES cryptographic key?

Tags: cryptography, aes

Is it crucial for AES to keep whole key in secret or it is possible, although not desirable to reveal for example first 4 chars of 16-char-long key? I want to use a part of key as a generator for a random number and curious what will happen if that part of key would be restored by an attacker. Should I split original key and use these two keys separately or it is ok to use original key along with the part of it? In other words:

```
function foo(data,key)
{
    smallKey = key.substr(0,Math.floor(key.length/4))
    return {
        out1: MD5(smallKey), // Could be cracked using rainbow tables
        out2: AES256CBC(data,key), // Uses the key containing the smallKey
    }
}

function boo(data,key)
{
    smallKey = key.substr(0,Math.floor(key.length/4))
    longKey = key.substr(smallKey.length - 1)
    return {
        out1: MD5(smallKey), // Could be cracked using rainbow tables
        out2: AES256CBC(data,longKey), // Uses the key not containing the smallKey
    }
}
```

Should I prefer using the foo which uses the longest key possible or should I prefer boo which uses totally different keys?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. The code may help understand the idea, but it is not necessary. You will certainly get better answers on [crypto.se] than on [so]. I found those questions and they should contain your answer: [decrypt AES without whole key](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5167/) and [Does it take brute force to find a pair of plaintext and ciphertext that each follow a certain condition, given an AES encryption key?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6062/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 4 bytes of the 16 byte key was leaked, you'd effectively reduce the strength of AES to at most 96-bits. There might be some partial key attack that reduces it further, but 96-bits would be the upper bound of strength.

You should absolutely use separate keys. If you have some constraint where you can't generate two cryptographically strong and unique keys, you could use [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) to stretch your AES key.

In that case, you'd derive the 2 keys from your master key. If one of the keys is leaked, it should be impossible to then go backwards and derive the master key.